# radare2 does not show reference to memory address

Tags: radare2

I am debugging Challenge 6 from the 2014 FlareOn challenges.
For incorrect imput it displays the "bad" message.
Running `/i bad` returns `0x004f3bf2 hit0_0 "bad"`.
`ps @ 0x004f3bf2` returns `bad` as expected.
My problem is that if I try to find reference to this memory address, `axt @ 0x004f3bf2`, `radare2` does not return anything, but the address is surely referenced:

```
pd 1 @ 0x43710c
0x0043710c      bff23b4f00     movl $0x4f3bf2, %edi        ; "bad" @ 0x4f3bf2
```

I have written a simple application containig `const char* bad="bad"; printf("%s\n", bad);`. In this case using the steps from above `radare2` correctly identifies the line calling `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because radare2 doesn't come with [analysis by default](http://radare.today/posts/analysis-by-default/), moreover, it doesn't have (yet?) great analysis capabilities. The reason why (beside the lack of time/interest/contributors of course) is explained in the previous link.

Also, please note that the string isn't referenced: during the disassembly, radare2 will detect strings and tell you about them, but this doesn't mean that it will add them to its internal database.

Comment: I have read the article and I need further reading to understand the different configuration variables. Currently I have `e file.analyze=true` in my `.radare2rc` file. What I do not understand, why I get no result for `axt @ 0x004f3bf2` in the challenge (www.flare-on.com/files/C6.zip), while doing the same steps in a simple helloworld applocation I get back the instruction which prepares the `printf`, with other words uses the address where the string is.

Comment: Because radare2 analysis is not super-great.